# Monacaでposition:fixedを使用するには

Tags: ios, monaca, css

お世話になっております。

Monacaでハイブリッドアプリを作成しております。

iOSの仕様
webkit-transparentが設定されている時
position:fixedが使用できず全てposition:staticになるため、
固定したいブロック要素が固定できずにいます(Android)では固定できています。

このような場合、どういった設定でブロック要素を固定すればよいのでしょうか？
ご存じの方がいらっしゃったらよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: Teratailでの同質問: https://teratail.com/questions/18152